# javascript continuous after form.submit() method called

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome, firefox, form-submit

When a `Asp.Net aspx` page on my site loads, a Javascript script runs a check on some condition, and if that condition is met, it should set an input element's value programmatically, and then submit the form, also programmatically, using form.submit(). With this, I am not using a `click` or `submit` event. The form should be processed backend and then the page reloaded with the correct data (and it does this correctly).

For some reason, this seems to work fine in FireFox, but it behaves differently in Chrome.

What is does in Firefox is that after the `form.submit()` the page reloads and my Javascript gets kicked off from the start (running the check again), as expected.

However, on Chrome, it seems that after the `form.submit()` call, the Javascript just continuous with the remaining Javascript code.
I tried the [form.requestSubmit()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/requestSubmit), but that didn't change it.

My code:

```
// check if someCondition is true, if so, a form field needs to be set prgrammatically and then the form submitted. If condition is false, just continue
if(someCondition){
   VerifyBeforeCheck();
}

DoTheNextThingIfConditionIsFalse(); //In Firefox, if VerifyBeforeCheck() is fired/ reached, this code never gets executed. In Chrome it will, but I don't want that.

// simple wrapper function, because SubmitMyForm gets called from different events and methods.
function VerifyBeforeCheck() {
    let newValue = sessionStorage.getItem("ItemFromSessionStorage");
    let fld = document.getElementById("formInputField"); // grabs an <input> field
    field.value = newValue; // used in backend
    SubmitMyForm();
}


function SubmitMyform(){
    let form = document.getElementById('myForm');
    form.submit();
}
```

Is this indeed unexpected behavior or am I missing something? I want the situation in Chrome to be as it is currently when I run it in Firefox: After the submit method, the form is submitted and then a page reload. If I need to use a preventDefault, how can I do this, without the event?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask].  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor. Seems to me you just need a preventDefault somewhere

Comment: I have no idea. Your code is not understandable and closer to pseudo code than runnable code. If you cannot explain better, then I am fraud I cannot help you

Comment: @mplungjan oke, thanks though, for your time and input. I tried to update the code as much as possible.

Comment: Why do you want to rely on the browser to ignore stuff after something that may or may not be async? Just add an else to `if(someCondition){
   VerifyBeforeCheck();
}
else DoTheNextThingIfConditionIsFalse();`